# How to prevent main process to lock UI after invoking multil

Tags: electron, node-worker-threads

I am building an app which list a set of files. When the user performs an action to one of the files, the action is process intensive (performs multiple ajax requests, updates an offline sqlite database, performs various checks on the file, etc). The user can trigger the said action on multiple files at a time.

The problem is that when the action is performed on more than one file, it blocks the UI. Digging down into the issue, removing certain part of the action (i.e. if I remove the section that performs a verification of the file size, type, and calculate the meta when missing, etc), it wears down the effect of UI lock, though it is still there.

From what I read so far, it is suggested to extract such logic out of the main process i.e. to have a separate process to handle those. The proposed solutions I've read are

- use worker thread
- create a child process
- create a server

I've been struggling to understand and come up with a working example for each. I came across this module named piscina which says to generate workers (my understanding it is a wrapper to create worker thread?).

On the repo [here](https://github.com/wyxos/electron-lock-main-process-example) I've setup an example which simulates the issue I have. So if I trigger multiple instances of the action by pressing the "Test" button at the bottom. And then try to increment the count at the top, I can experience the UI lock/lags. It takes approximately 10-15 clicks on the "Test" button to replicate. I can also hear the CPU fan increasing when performing this.

Are there any projects/examples around which gives a simplified implementation on how to mitigate or work around this problem?

#### EDIT

After @tromgy suggestions I've performed the following updates/test:

- Adjusting the await run to a regular promise did seem to solve the issue.
- But triggering multiple instances simultaneously, for example, 20, still causes UI lock. Attempting the same on my actual project causes memory heap errors.
- I tried moving the Piscina instance outside, rather than creating a new instance on each event, it solves the memory leap, but not the UI lock/lag/freeze issue.
- I've tried converting invoke to an actual event, the UI issue still persist.

Comment: The problem is that you "oversynchronized" your code. The `testEvent` handler is waiting until the worker thread is done. It shouldn't. Use `.then` instead of `await`. When the worker thread is done (the code in `.then` will execute), it can send some other message to the renderer indicating the result.

Comment: From your comment, does it then make sense to not use ```.invoke``` but use ```.send``` when going for this type of task/action?

Comment: @tromgy reason I ask the above is that even if I change the worker to a then, doesn't the UI still wait for the promise due to the .invoke or am I missing something?

Comment: @tromgy I experimented on the same example with what you advised and it seems to indeed prevent the UI lock. Though I am not sure to understand why in the sense that I thought await was syntactic sugar and is supposed to work the same way as writing an actual promise. I will test the same on the actual app and advise.

Comment: I've made some updates and will edit the question

Comment: I've looked at your change, and I think you could improve the performance by batching, that is making one `invoke` call with a parameter specifying the number of requests instead of calling `invoke` in the loop multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately in my use case, these actions may be triggered by the user multiple times on several items. They will not be exactly in the format of a loop. For example there may be 100 items listed, and the user can click on 40 of them, but 10 needs to process at a time. I tried a combination of using maxQueue on piscina but that doesn't give me the desired effect.

Comment: I updated the repo further and it seems a combination of queue + piscina does alleviate the load. In the actual app though I can observe that the operation that's causing a heavy load relates to a heavy database operation. Extracting the same into a worker or queue does not seem to help. I'll update further if I make additional findings.